# VirtualAlloc() working on certain memory addresses but not others

Tags: c, api, memory, operating-system, virtualalloc

I'm running a program called VMdriver5.exe (left side of image I attached), that creates a process of another program called VMmapper.exe. Inside the VMdriver5.c code, it gets its PID (using GetCurrentProcessId()) and passes it's PID to VMmapper.exe upon creation, such that VMmapper shows the memory layout of VMdriver5.exe so I can see the virtual memory options.

[image: VirtualAlloc failing on a free region of memory]

I was wondering if I could get some help, because, when I call VirtualAlloc() on certain memory addresses, it works fine. However, as you can see in the image below, there is a region of memory with 503,808 bytes free, and I attempt to **reserve** 65,536 bytes of that space using VirtualAlloc(), but it fails for some reason. I pass the memory address 00185000 as one of the parameters.

The code I'm using is this:

```
lpvAddr = VirtualAlloc(vmAddress, units << 16, MEM_RESERVE, flProtect); // only works with PAGE_READONLY
            if(lpvAddr == NULL) {
               printf("Case 1: Reserve a region, VirtualAlloc() failed. Error: %ld\n", GetLastError());
            }
            else {
               printf("Committed %lu bytes at address 0x%lp\n",dwPageSize, lpvAddr); // %lu = long unsigned decimal integer
            }
            break;
```

I would appreciate any help and can provide any more code or info if needed. Thanks guys and happy easter.

Comment: See [documentation for VirtualAlloc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc)

Comment: What does GetLastError tell you? Now you need to translate the error code.